# How to append image name and download url to logged in users node in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I m trying to upload image to firebase storage and as per my need it is going to storage perfectly but in firebase database I m facing 2 isssues

1. When I upload image the download Url is not the same which I see in storage. It appears to be something 
   like 
   `""com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@590df7c"`
2. The details of uploaded image is not appending to logged in users node. Instead it is uploading to database in separate node.

   ```
   public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   private static final int CHOOSE_IMAGE = 101;
   String Database_Path = "users";
   String Storage_Path = "profilepics/";
   TextView textView;
   private ImageView imageView;
   EditText editText;
   Uri uriProfileImage;
   String downloadUri;
   ProgressBar progressBar;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
   String imageUrl;
   Button UploadButton;


   StorageReference storageReference;
   DatabaseReference databaseReference;


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

   mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

   editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDisplayName);
   imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
   UploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
   progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);


   storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
   databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Database_Path);

   progressBar = new ProgressBar(SecondActivity.this)
      imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
               showimagechooser();
       }
   });

   UploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {

           // Calling method to upload selected image on Firebase storage.

           startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, DisplayProfile.class));

       }
   });
    }

   private void showimagechooser() {
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setType("image/*");
   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select profile Image"), CHOOSE_IMAGE);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
   {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

   if (requestCode == CHOOSE_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
       uriProfileImage = data.getData();
       try {
           Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uriProfileImage);
           imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
           uploadImageToFirebaseStorage(bitmap);

          } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
    }

    private void uploadImageToFirebaseStorage(Bitmap bitmap) {
   final String TempImageName = editText.getText().toString().trim();

   FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
   final StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
   String userID=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
   System.out.println(userID);
   // this is how you set your desired name for the image
   final StorageReference ImagesRef = storageRef.child("images/"+mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()+".jpg");


   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
   byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
   final UploadTask uploadTask = ImagesRef.putBytes(data);

   uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
       @Override
       public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
           Log.i("whatTheFuck:",exception.toString());
       }
   }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>(){
                               @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                               @Override
                               public void onSuccess(final UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                   Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                                       @Override
                                       public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                                           if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                               Log.i("problem", task.getException().toString());
                                           }

                                           return ImagesRef.getDownloadUrl();
                                       }
                                   }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                                           if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                               Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();

                                               DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                                               ref.child("imageURL").setValue(downloadUri.toString());
                                               ref.child("imageName").setValue(TempImageName);


                                           } else {
                                               Log.i("wentWrong","downloadUri failure");
                                           }
                                       }
                                   });
                               }
   });

    }
    }
   ```

Here is link to My database
[Database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZOUQ.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey @Mk, did my answer help you solve your problem?

Comment: The way you get the download URL from an upload has changed. See the [documentation on getting a download URL after uploading a file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url), or one of these questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299915/how-to-get-offline-uploded-file-download-url-in-firebase, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53127996/getdownloadurl-isnt-inputting-the-link-i-need/53128190#53128190, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730647/firebase-storage-bug-trying-to-insert-data-into-my-database/52740955#52740955

Comment: nothing worked that's why I posted this question

Answer (score 1):

Yes @Yupi is right, you're not correctly getting the correct url for your image. For getting the correct url of your uploaded image, you can use a code like this:

```java
private void uploadFile(Bitmap bitmap) {

        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        final StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();

         // this is how you set your desired name for the image
        final StorageReference ImagesRef = storageRef.child("images/"+mAu.getCurrentUser().getUid()+".jpg");


        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
        byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
        final UploadTask uploadTask = ImagesRef.putBytes(data);

        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                Log.i("whatTheFuck:",exception.toString());
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
               // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.

                Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.i("problem", task.getException().toString());
                        }

                        return ImagesRef.getDownloadUrl(); 
                    }
                }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();

                            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(mAu.getCurrentUser().getUid());


                            Log.i("seeThisUri", downloadUri.toString());// This is the link or name you should use to save or set the image

                            ref.child("imageURL").setValue(downloadUri.toString());


                        } else {
                            Log.i("wentWrong","downloadUri failure");
                        }
                    }
                });
             }
        });

    }
```

This code also contains instances of how to upload url to the Firebase Database, and I think this might help you in your code.

Comment: where should I add above code

Comment: Your code is creating url and solved my problem no 1 but as I asked it Is not appending url details to logged in users node.It is Creating new node and adding  details to that node

Comment: I managed to both problems but the image name in firebase have no value or showing empty value

Comment: Can you edit your code question above and put the code you're having problems with, I can look into it.

Comment: edited my question now can you help me?

Comment: What is going wrong with the code, right now?

Comment: image name in database gets empty value

Comment: If you're putting the name using `edit.getText().toString()` then check if you're not leaving the field empty and getting the correct text.

Comment: NO I a Not leaving the feild empty

Comment: Are you referring to the image name in your Firebase Storage or image Url in Firebase Database?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not uploading image correctly that means you are not getting real image url. I think you are missing one part of code. So inside `onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot)` add:

```
storageReference2nd.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            String imageUrl = uri.toString() // this is your image url 
                           // which you want to send on database
                        }
                    });
```